# filter elements bound with jQuery "on" method

Tags: jquery, bind

i would like to bind events to all elements in the body but a container and its descendants and have trouble getting it working. Let's say the html markup is :

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div>
        <label>Click here (should not alert)</label>    
    </div>
</div>

 <label>Click here (should alert)</label>
```

i first tried with:

```
$("body, body *").not(".myDiv, .myDiv *").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e.target);
});
```

but the alert fires on both label (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DrbD/1/)). I got the same results with the following:

```
$("body, body *").on("click", ":not(.myDiv)", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e.target);
});
```

i managed to achieve what i want with (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4FzXd/1/)):

```
$("body, body *").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents(".myDiv, .myDiv *").length == 0) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert(e.target);
    }
});
```

but i don't understand why the two previous ways don't produce the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that jQuery is matching exactly what you tell him to, so when you write:

```
$("body, body *").not(".myDiv, .myDiv *").on("click", function(e) {
```

it's going to match the `body` first, and then *every* descendant, when you filter with `not` you leave out `.myDiv` and it's childs but you still keep the body.

The same happens here:

```
$("body, body *").on("click", ":not(.myDiv)", function(e) {
```

So, even if your not selector is correct, the body element still has an event attached to it, that is why your last bit of code works, it's firing the event in the body and asking what to filter later.

To fix this you could do:

```
$("body *").not(".myDiv, .myDiv *").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e.target);
});
```

I recommend you log in the console ( `console.log` ) the result of the selectors, so you can get a better understanding of what's happening

Good luck!